# Как делают доработку сайтов?

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование

Допустим, заказчику нужно доработать сайт на вордпресс. Я прошу данные админ панели и данные ftp. Переносить на локалку очень долго еще и конфиги надо менять. А если работать напрямую через filezilla, боюсь что то поломать. Как разработчики делают всякие доработки??

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123254/discussion-on-question-by------).

Answer (score -1):

> Как разработчики делают всякие доработки??

Смотря какие "доработки".
Некоторые мелочи можно и на породакшене делать. Но что-то чуть серьёзнее делается на тестовом сайте-клоне. И не на "локалке", а на реальном хостинге. Лучше всего на том же, где сайт будет жить.

Миграция же делается с пом. специальных средств. Одно из простых и удобных -  https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/ Подробнее см [Как правильно перенести сайт на WordPress?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767561/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%B0-wordpress/767562#767562)